# How to know which jdbc data source my application is using in websphere application server 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, jndi, websphere-7

I have ear file running in ibm websphere application server . Which uses data source to connect to database (Oracle).
Without logging into ibm admin console. 
I can't find it in resources.xml

Comment: What is the scope of the data source for which you're looking and are you looking for resources.xml at that scope?

Comment: @FRowe scope means , are you referring to cells or profiles in WAS. To be simple, I have an application that was deployed by someone in WAS and running currently in live - I would like to know which jdbc data source it's using?

Answer (score 0):

The `resource.xml` is present on many levels, you can have it in cell, node, server or cluster level, so maybe you are looking in wrong folder. But that will only give you DataSource definition.

To find out mapping between application and datasource, the application has to use *resource references*, then you will be able to find binding between reference and actual JNDI name in the binding files.

You can find the binding files either with application (`PROFILE_ROOT/installedApps/cellName\application.ear`)  or in the deployments folder (e.g. `PROFILE_ROOT/config/cells/cellName/applications/application.ear/deployments/application/module/` then either `WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml` or  `META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`)

If application is just using external JNDI name in the code directly you will not have binding, and you will have to find out that mapping by yourself, probably from application code or some configuration property files.